# How to display data from database in listView - POWERBUILDER 11.0

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm new in PowerBuilder. Anyone can give me code or tutorial on how to display data from database in ListView? I only know additem() and setitem() functions. Please help, Thank you!

Comment: You want to look into the DataWindow.

Answer (score 1):

If you know additem() function you know how to add elements to the ListView. You only need to get the data from the database and insert it in the ListView. There are at least two ways to achieve it:

1. Using [cursor statements](https://docs.appeon.com/pb2021/connecting_to_your_database/ch06s01.html#XREF_86952_ODBC_Cursor)
2. Using a [DataStore](https://docs.appeon.com/pb2021/objects_and_controls/ch02s18.html). DataStores are the same as DataWindows but without a visual layer.